# Running Celery as a daemon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon, rabbitmq

I'm testing Celery with RabbitMQ on Ubuntu11.04 on a python project that is not a django project.
I have my celeryconfig.py and my test.py file in /mypath/myproject/.
My `/etc/default/celeryd` looks like this:

```
# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR= "/mypath/myproject/"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS=”–time-limit=300”

# Name of the celery config module.#
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE=”celeryconfig”
```

When I run `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start` I get this error message:

```
/etc/default/celeryd: line 2: /mypath/myproject/: Is a directory
```

Any ideas? I followed [these instructions](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/cookbook/daemonizing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Its the extra space after the equals sign. You want:

```
CELERYD_CHDIR="/mypath/myproject/"
```